# SoapUI import from swagger yaml does not work when parameter definition is behind refference $ref

Tags: soapui, openapi

we have a swagger spec file in yaml and we are using $ref for parameter definition because the same parameter is used in multiple (many) endpoints.

SoapUI version is 5.7.0

But when import gets to this part of the code it fails and I receive error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.equals(Object)" because the return value of "io.swagger.models.parameters.Parameter.getIn()" is null
```

I looks like the import can not expand the $ref in to the parameter definition written behind the reference.

Is there a solution for this, please?

Here I put the part of the code where it fails. In swagger editor this is a valid code without any errors.

```
openapi: 3.0.2
info:
  title: REST API
  description: "Test yaml for SoapUI import."
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
- url: /
  description: test
security:
- Auth: []
paths:
  /rest/fcc/users/{id}:
    get:
      tags:
      - FCC users and roles
      summary: Gets user with given id
      description: Returns user with given id.
      parameters:
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/id'
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful opperation
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/User_one'
        '404':
          description: Entity with given id does not exist
    delete:
      tags:
      - FCC users and roles
      summary: Deletes user with given id
      description: Removes user with given id.
      parameters:
      - $ref: '#/components/parameters/id'
      responses:
        '204':
          description: Successful deletion
components:
  securitySchemes:
    Auth:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        password:
          tokenUrl: /resources/oauth/token
          scopes: {}
  parameters:
    id:
      name: id
      in: path
      required: true
      schema:
        type: integer
        example: 2
  schemas:
    User_one:
      type: object
```

Comment: Your OpenAPI definition is correct. I suggest you send a bug report to SoapUI developers.

Comment: I posted Question on smartbear community site almost week ago, but still no reaction to it.